# How to update/override transitive NPM dependencies?

Tags: jquery, angular, npm

I want to upgrade jQuery to v3.5.0 or higher as it has a fix which I require. What is the way to do that?

I don't think I should do a npm install `jquery@3.5.0` as it would list `cookie-signature` in my app dependencies.

I want to override the transitive dependency.

Tried all of these things.

Identify the package and version of the transitive dependency that needs to be updated. You can do this by running the command `npm list <package-name>` in your project directory to see the version of the package and its dependencies.

Once you have identified the package and version that needs to be updated, update it in your project's `package.json` file by running the command `npm install <package-name>@<version> --save`.

After updating the package, you should run the command `npm install` to install the updated package and its dependencies.

Once the installation is complete, you should rebuild your Angular application by running the command `ng serve` or `ng build`.